# Exclude exact word on many columns dosn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table category and products and I'm doing filtering with many methods on the rows.

This is my data :

Table Category :

> ```
> Id  Libelle   Description
> 1   Animals   dogs
> 2   Kids      games
> ```

Table Product :

> ```
> Id  Name   Category_Id
> 1   aaa kkk   2
> 2   bbb kkk   2
> ```

There is a FK between these two tables.

This is my first query I select rows and then I want to exclude the row if `category.Libelle` OR `Category.Description` match some word :

```
select distinct * from category cat 
JOIN product pro on pro.Category_Id = cat.Id
where (MATCH (pro.Name) 
AGAINST( 'kkk'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
AND
(concat(cat.Libelle , cat.Description) 
NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]kids[[:>:]]')
```

Here the result is not correct it returns 2 rows except that must return 0 rows why ?

The second query I want the same purpose but I will check with `product.Name` :

```
select distinct * from category cat  
JOIN product pro on pro.Category_Id = cat.Id
where (MATCH (pro.Name) 
AGAINST( 'kkk'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
AND pro.Name NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]bbb[[:>:]]'
```

Here I have as result one row that is it :

```
'2', 'kids', 'games', '1', 'aaa kkk', '2'
```

But I want to exclude that row also, so I want exclude the row of the category if any of the Name of list Product `pro.Name` associated with `Category_Id` contains exact word 'bbb', So I want a result of 0 row and not 1 row, How can I do it ?

Comment: in your table Category "Kids" starts with a capital, in your regex "kids" starts with a lower case

Comment: @Kendle No that is not the problem because with upper Kids in REGEXP dosn't work also

Comment: When you say “match some word”, do you mean equal to a word or like a word?

Comment: @NickW exact word not like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is to concat all columns of the parent table, in addition of all child rows associated grouped by method group concat :

```
select distinct cat.* ,  concat(coalesce(cat.Libelle , ' ') , ' ', coalesce(cat.Description, ' ') , ' ' , group_concat(distinct coalesce(pro.libelle , ' ') separator ' ')) as listConcat
```

And than Checking with `HAVING` for all rows returned by the select :

```
HAVING listConcat RLIKE
```

Answer (score 0):

Will a simple WHERE clause not work? e.g.

```
WHERE category.Libelle <> ‘kids’ 
AND Category.Description <> ‘kids’
```

Comment: No dosn't work incorrect syntax

Comment: Did you make any attempt to check/fix the syntax - for example the type of quote marks?

Comment: dosn't work with 'kids' also I'm using Mysql 80

Comment: What’s the exact SQL query you are running and what do you mean by “doesn’t work”? Does it error (and what’s the error message), does it not return the expected rows?